# Getting Error 503 when sending request via heroku or any host not local

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-503

my Node.js server is supposed to send a GET request to a third-party website vie https.get, but that website returns a 503 error, which is strange, because when I send the exact same request from my own device everything works as intended. Does anybody know what may be the cause of this problem, and how it can be fixed?

EDIT: The website uses CloudFlare, it might be related to theproblem but still - it works in my device.
Checking if the site connection is
shahed4u.vip needs to review the security of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using cloudflare it's just normal, because cloudflare prevent access to bots.

> Note: all informatical program making HTTP request are bots, is considered as "true clients" by cloudflare browsers with graphical instance, cookies, and algorythm (check [this article on how cloudflare detect "bots"](https://www.zenrows.com/blog/bypass-cloudflare))